# (JSON.NET) RuntimeBinderException accessing dynamic JObject (works on one PC, fails on another)

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio, dynamic, json.net

I use Json.net to deserialize a json string to a dynamic object:

```
var initialJSON = "{ 'artillery': { 'status': '0', 'code': '' }, 'diplomacy': { 'status': '0', 'code': '' }, 'seccheck': { 'status': '0', 'code': '' }, 'march': { 'status': '0', 'code': '' }, 'production': { 'status': '0', 'code': '' }, 'water': { 'status': '0', 'code': '' }, 'technology': { 'status': '0', 'code': '' }, 'spy': { 'status': '0', 'code': '' }, 'weapon': { 'status': '1', 'code': '' }, 'raid': { 'status': '0', 'code': '' }, 'prod_artillery': { 'status': '1', 'code': '' }, 'prod_bio': { 'status': '1', 'code': '' }, 'prod_nuclear': { 'status': '1', 'code': '' }, 'prod_hacking': { 'status': '1', 'code': '' }, 'prod_covops': { 'status': '1', 'code': '' }, 'prod_tank': { 'status': '1', 'code': '' }, 'prod_infantry': { 'status': '1', 'code': '' }, 'prod_fighter': { 'status': '1', 'code': '' }, 'prod_ship': { 'status': '1', 'code': '' }, 'prod_submarine': { 'status': '1', 'code': '' }, 'prod_general': { 'status': '1', 'code': '' }, 'weapon_bio': { 'status': '1', 'code': '' }, 'weapon_nuclear': { 'status': '1', 'code': '' }, 'weapon_covops': { 'status': '1', 'code': '' }, 'weapon_hacking': { 'status': '1', 'code': '' } }";
var actionData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(initialJSON);
```

I'm working on a team foundation server project with a colleague.
After the deserialization I can access the properties like this:

```
actionData.production.status = "1";
```

But when my colleague runs the same line of code, he gets a RuntimeBinderException:

> 'actionData.production' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException'    dynamic
>
> 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for
>   'production'

While comparing we noticed that he doesn't get the "Dynamic View" on actionData:

**My View:**

[image: actionData with Dynamic View]

**His View:**

[image: actionData without Dynamic View]

How is that even possible?

We compared our Debugger/Exception Settings, they were 100% equal.
Same VS Version, same project version by TFS etc.

I'm absolutely aware that I could avoid dynamic and use real objects.

But I'm extremely curious where this difference could come from.

Comment: Are you using the same versions of Json.NET?  You can see by doing `Debug.WriteLine("Json.NET version: " + typeof(JToken).Assembly.FullName);`.

Comment: We have both the same version (7.0.0.0)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue in VS 2012. To solve this, you have to enable "Just My Code" in your solution.
Go to Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General, and hit the box "Enable Just My Code", press OK. Now it shoul work.

[image: Debugging window screen]